# Unable to pass a profile to Capybara when creating a new driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm using a ruby/cucumber/capybara framework with versions:

```
capybara (2.10.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.0.0)
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]
```

and I'm trying to register a new driver with some settings passed in the profile to capybara. My code looks like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :debug do |app|  
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```

and I've tried as well with:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
```

Then I just use the following to select that driver:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :debug
```

but in both cases, when I try to run any test, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000000068ca798 @model=nil, @native_events=true, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={}, @extensions={}>}
```

Any idea what the problem could be? and how to ammend it?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Profiles are not yet supported in Ruby bindings for geckodriver, which is needed for Firefox 48+. Watch this issue for (hopefully very soon) resolution: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2933